# Compilando Python desde cmd

Tags: python, cmd

mi codigo desde Visual SC se ejecuta perfectamente, pero cuando lo intento desde la cmd me da el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\Guardado\UdemyCurso>00Ficheros.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\Guardado\UdemyCurso\00Ficheros.py", line 6, in <module>
    archivo = open("Guardado/UdemyCurso/texto.txt", "a+")#Abre el archivo, sino, lo crea
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Guardado/UdemyCurso/texto.txt'
```

El codigo en mi editor es este:

```
fichero_leer = open("Guardado/UdemyCurso/texto.txt", "r")

contenido = fichero_leer.read()

for elemento in contenido:
    print(elemento, end="")
```

Y esto es lo que devuelve cuando lo ejecuto desde Visual Studio Code:

```
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
Soy un texto insertado desde Python
```

Comment: El path donde se encuentra el archivo es incorrecto, me parece que se encuentra en   la misma ubicación que el script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto no es un problema de python exclusivamente.

Siempre que se ejecuta un programa en Windows, Linux y otros sistemas operativos, el entorno de ejecución de este programa mantiene el registro de la *carpeta actual de trabajo* (también conocida como *directorio actual de trabajo* o simplmente *directorio actual* del programa. Es como si la sesión del programa estuviera  *situada* (por decirlo de alguna forma) en una carpeta del sistema operativo.

Cuando se hace operaciones con archivos y se pasa al sistema operativo una ruta relativa, para este la ruta es relativa a la carpeta actual del programa.

Así, si tu llamas a

```
x = open("carpeta/archivo.txt")
```

Y la ruta actual es `c:\abc`, el programa intentará abrir el archivo `c:\abc\carpeta\archivo.txt`.

Evidentemente, cuando ejecutas el script desde dentro del IDE de Visual Studio, la ejecución tiene una carpeta actual distinta de la que tiene si lo lanzas desde la línea de comandos.

Lo habitual, cuando lanzas un programa desde la línea de comandos, es que la carpeta actual inicial del programa sea la carpeta donde te encuentras en tu sesión interactiva de la línea de comandos. Supongo que en Visual Studio, la carpeta actual podría ser la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo principal del proyecto, pero no tengo experiencia con python en VS, así que es una pura suposición.

Tienes varias soluciones:

- A la hora de abrir el archivo, utiliza una ruta absoluta, y no relativa. En Windows las rutas absolutas comienzan con

  - una letra de unidad de la forma `X:\xxx`
  - la cadena `\\`
- Asegurate de iniciar siempre el script en la misma ruta donde lo inicia Visual Studio, en base a lo que puedo intuir, quizás esto resuelva el problema (en una sesión de comandos):

  ```
    c:\>cd \Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY
    c:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY>Guardado\UdemyCurso>00Ficheros.py
  ```

  - Cambia el directorio actual desde dentro del programa, con [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir), por ejemplo, antes de abrir el archivo:

    ```
    os.chdir(r"c:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY")
    ```

Puedes averiguar cual es el directorio actual con la ayuda de [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd):

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print("Directorio actual: {0}".format(cwd))
```

Finalmente solo indicar que python no es un lenguaje compilado, por lo que no estás compilando. Python es un lenguaje interpretado, por lo que estás invocando al interprete, que es el que va interpretando y ejecutando el script a medida que va avanzando en su ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que no encuentra el archivo:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'Guardado/UdemyCurso/texto.txt'

De acuerdo a tu código, el archivo `texto.txt` debería ubicarse en la ruta:

```
C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\Guardado\UdemyCurso\Guardado\UdemyCurso\
```

ya que tu script se encuentra en:

```
C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\Guardado\UdemyCurso\
```

pero el archivo a leer lo tratas de abrir en "Guardado\UdemyCurso":

```
fichero_leer = open("Guardado/UdemyCurso/texto.txt", "r")
```

si tu archivo se encuentra en la misma ubicación donde se encuentra tu script simplemente ábrelo de esta forma:

```
fichero_leer = open("texto.txt", "r")

contenido = fichero_leer.read()

for elemento in contenido:
    print(elemento, end="")
```