# Tkinter no acepta la ruta de mi icono

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un objeto encargado de cargar mi ventana segun los parametros que pide con el constructor de la clase. Todos los parametros recibidos estan bien, salvo la ruta al icono q establecí en el main con os.path.
Este es el main:

```
from tkinter import*
import os.path
from TkinterClassMetodos import graficos

ruta_ico = os.path.abspath("./img/IcoPython.ico")

ventana = graficos("Ventana", ruta_ico, "300x250", False)
ventana.cargar()
ventana.mostrar()
```

Esta es la clase:

```
class graficos:
    def __init__(self, nom_Ventana, rootIco, tamaño, resizable = True):
        self.nom_Ventana = nom_Ventana
        self.rootIco = rootIco
        self.tamaño = tamaño
        self.resizable = resizable

    def mostrar(self):
        self.ventana.mainloop()

    def cargar(self):
        ventana = Tk()
        self.ventana = ventana
        ventana.iconbitmap(self.rootIco)#Aqui está el error
        ventana.title(self.nom_Ventana)
        ventana.geometry(self.tamaño)

        if self.resizable == True:
            ventana.resizable(1,1)
        else:
            ventana.resizable(0,0)

    def addText(self):
        texto = Label(self.ventana, text="Hola")
        texto.pack()
```

Este es el error q da en consola:

```
File "C:\Users\Ariana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2072, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\img\IcoPython.ico" not defined
```

Alguien sabe qué significa?

Comment: ¿Y si está el archivo del ícono en la ruta que te muestra el mensaje de error?

Comment: Tuve q cambiar la linea: ruta_ico = os.path.abspath("./img/IcoPython.ico") por: ruta_ico = os.path.abspath("./Graficos/Udemy_Tkinter/img/IcoPython.ico")

Comment: Lee esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/445784/21, es a un síntima diferente, del mismo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
import TkinterClassMetodos as m

ruta_ico = os.path.abspath("./img/IcoPython.ico")

Ventana = m.Graficos("Ventana", ruta_ico, "300x250", False)
Ventana.cargar()
Ventana.mostrar()
```

**TkinterClassMetodos.py**

```
from tkinter import *

class Graficos:
    def __init__(self, nom_Ventana, rootIco, tamaño, resizable = True):
        self.nom_Ventana = nom_Ventana
        self.rootIco = rootIco
        self.tamaño = tamaño
        self.resizable = resizable

    def mostrar(self):
        self.ventana.mainloop()

    def cargar(self):
        ventana = Tk()
        self.ventana = ventana
        ventana.iconbitmap(self.rootIco)#Aqui está el error
        ventana.title(self.nom_Ventana)
        ventana.geometry(self.tamaño)

        if self.resizable == True:
            ventana.resizable(1,1)
        else:
            ventana.resizable(0,0)

    def addText(self):
        texto = Label(self.ventana, text="Hola")
        texto.pack()
```

He cambiado la forma en que se importa el módulo y ahora me ha funcionado correctamente. He descargado una imagen `.ico` de prueba. Se abre una ventana cuyo icono es esa imagen.