# Otro error operacional Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

La verdad no sé que le pica a esto, porque ayer funcionaba bien, hice muchos registros, pero hoy Sqlite decide q 'Coches' no es una tabla, aunque si lo es y ayer la reconocía.

Aqui está la funcion que maneja la BD:

```
def consultar():
    conexion = sqlite3.connect("BDFlask_Sqlite.db")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    datos = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Coches")
    return datos
```

y Aqui está la prueba que Coches SI es una tabla y claramente SI existe.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe que diablos le pasa a Sqlite q de pronto da errores operacionales que anteriormente no estaban? Porque esta funcion para consultar no ha sido modificada en un buen rato. Es cosa de Flask? Porque en Django esto nunca me ha pasado.

Comment: Veo que le pasas una ruta relativa al abrir la base de datos, quizás algo cambió en tu entorno o en el código y ahora la carpeta actual a la hora que abres la base de datos ya no es la misma. Recuerda que SQLite, por defecto, cuando tratas de abrir una base de datos que no existe, la crea... quizás sea mejor que pases la ruta absoluta del archivo de base de datos, o que te asegures que la carpeta actual de tu programa es la que debe ser, antes de realizar la operación de apertura.

Comment: Ya noté q pasó, no se como ni cuando, pero el archivo .db cambió de lugar y fue reemplazado por una base de datos vacia con el mismo nombra. Gracias.

Comment: Puede ser que haya cambiado de lugar en alguna operación que hiciste sin prestar mucha atención, me alegra que lo hayas encontrado. Para que no quede lo dicho en comentarios, ya que puede ayudar a alguien más en el futuro, escribí una respuesta. Un saludo y me alegra que lo resolvieras.

Comment: Gracias, a veces hago lo mismo con mis propias preguntas, si encuentro solucion antes que alguien me escriba.

Comment: Perfecto, Ariana, esa es justamente la idea del sitio, si encuentras la solución, publicala como respuesta (y acéptala cuando pasa el tiempo que el sitio te pide para aceptar una auto-respuesta, creo que 2 días), pues la idea es ayudar a otros también en el futuro.  Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que le pasas una ruta relativa al abrir la base de datos:

```
conexion = sqlite3.connect("BDFlask_Sqlite.db")
```

Quizás algo cambió en tu entorno o en el código y ahora la carpeta actual, a la hora que abres la base de datos, ya no es la misma que era hace unos días, cuando *todo funcionaba*.

Primero, recuerda que SQLite, por defecto, cuando tratas de abrir una base de datos que no existe, en lugar de dar un error, la crea. Entonces, esa nueva base de datos no va a contener ni la tabla `coches` ni ninguna otra que hayas creado antes.

Quizás sea mejor que pases la ruta absoluta del archivo de base de datos, o que te asegures que la carpeta actual de tu programa es la que debe ser, antes de realizar la operación de apertura.

Para pasar una ruta absoluta, por ejemplo:

```
conexion = sqlite3.connect(r"c:\users\juan\prueba\BDFlask_Sqlite.db")
```

Para cambiar la carpeta actual del programa, por ejemplo:

```
os.chdir(r"c:\Users\juan\prueba")
conexion = sqlite3.connect("BDFlask_Sqlite.db")
```

En otra respuesta he dado una explicación sobre [carpeta actual, rutas absolutas y relativas en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/445784/21), que quizás quieras leer para aclararte sobre el tema.