# Problema con archivos .ui en Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Estoy empezando a practicar con las interfaces gráficas del *QtDesigner* copiando algunos ejemplos de la red.
Al ejecutar mi código, el diseño que hice en el *QtDesigner* no me aparece, sino me aparece un error.
¿estoy cargando mal el archivo .ui?
La versión de Python que tengo es 3.9.5 de 64bits

Mi código en Python es:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class Form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi('ejemplo.ui',self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Form()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

el error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\_Datos\01. Proyectos VS+\PyVigas\ejemplo.py", line 15, in <module>
    widget = Form()
  File "d:\_Datos\01. Proyectos VS+\PyVigas\ejemplo.py", line 10, in __init__
    loadUi('ejemplo.ui',self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 238, in loadUi
    return DynamicUILoader(package).loadUi(uifile, baseinstance, resource_suffix)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Loader\loader.py", line 66, in loadUi     
    return self.parse(filename, resource_suffix)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 1020, in parse
    document = parse(filename)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1229, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 569, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ejemplo.ui'
```

Agradecería mucho que pudiesen ayudarme por favor.

Comment: Que te sale al ejecutarlo? un error? o simplemente se ejecuta y termina el proceso?

Comment: Me sale la ventana vacía con el título Python como si no hubiera nada en el .ui
https://postimg.cc/gXLkYHcp

Comment: ¿Si existe el archivo `ejemplo.ui` en la ruta actual en tiempo de ejecución?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/445784/21

Comment: el error está en def _init_(self): se usa doble subrayado: def __init__(self):

Comment: TYPO: cambia `def _init_(self):` to `def __init__(self):`

Comment: Sí tengo ejemplo.ui en la ruta actual, tienen razón con lo de los guiones bajos, sin embargo ahora tengo otro error que comienza con:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\_Datos\01. Proyectos VS+\PyVigas\Propiedades del material concreto.py", line 15, in <module>
    widget = Form()
  File "d:\_Datos\01. Proyectos VS+\PyVigas\Propiedades del material concreto.py", line 10, in __init__
    loadUi('ejemplo.ui',self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 238, in loadUi
.
.
.
.`

Comment: @ReynaldoML 1) Edita tu post y coloca el mensaje de error completo, 2) Nunca uses espacios en los nombres de los archivos .py ya que pueden generar problemas. 3) Prueba cambiando `ejemplo.ui` con su ruta completa.

Comment: @eyllanesc, también corregí poniendo la ruta completa sin embargo el error persiste

Comment: prueba con: `import os.path` `filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
            os.path.realpath(__file__)), "ejemplo.ui")` `loadUi(filename, self)`

Comment: ¿y por qué no poner el script y el *.ui en el mismo directorio?

Comment: @tincopasan sí están en el mismo directorio

Comment: @eyllanesc genial, muchas gracias. Con tu ayuda lo pude resolver, ahora podrías explicarme cómo funciona lo que me enviaste y por qué no funciona usando el código similar a otros que encontré en la red?